# Cannot install nvidia-prime

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 22.04

Brand-spanking new Ubuntu 22.04 installation. Using a Lenovo Thinkpad P72 with nVidia Quadro P5200.

System says I am using the integrated Mesa Intel UHD Graphics P630 driver. I want to switch to discrete graphics, but `nvidia-prime` is not a recognized command, and also does not appear in the Applications launcher.

When I try:

```
>sudo apt install --reinstall nvidia-prime
```

I get:

```
Reinstallation if nvidia-prime is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
```

**Is there some other nvidia utility I am supposed to be using in Ubuntu 22.04? Is there some other path to using nvidia-prime?**

Comment: You're supposed to install the Nvidia drivers. Prime comes with it.

Comment: @ChanganAuto The nvidia 510 meta-package is installed.