# Ubuntu 22.04 Nvidia-settings not working anymore

Tags: nvidia, xorg, nvidia-settings, xorg.conf

Since I switched to Ubuntu 22.04 I have the problem that I am not able to store my Monitor to 155 hertz refresh rate in the nvidia-settings.

It lets me change the refresh rate, but after a reboot, the monitor is reverting back to the original 60Hz instead of my chosen 155Hz.

My graphics card is a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 and my kernel version is 5.15.0-41-generic.

My /etc/X11/xorg.conf file looks like this:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 510.73.05

# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 510.47.03

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Dell S2719DGF"
    HorizSync       250.0 - 250.0
    VertRefresh     40.0 - 155.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "2560x1440_155 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

So the screen section looks fine to me.
Anyone else notice anything?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: What version of kernel are you using?

Comment: 5.15.0-41-generic

Comment: +1 [I cannot launch `nvidia-settings` or `nvidia-prime` in Ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1418601/cannot-install-nvidia-prime).